# Javascript: ReferenceError: check is not defined

Tags: javascript, websocket, k6

I am trying to do some load testing on websockets with k6 but on the run it keeps giving me this error:

```
ERRO[0011] ReferenceError: check is not defined
```

It is pointing to my check function at the bottom but I am not sure why this error is being thrown and what I am doing wrong.

Code error is pointed to

```
check(response, {
    "WebSocket connection is successful": (res) =>
      res && res.json().type === "completed" && res.error === undefined,
  });
```

Full code:

```
import ws from "k6/ws";

export let options = {
  vus: 1,
  iterations: 1,
};

export default function () {
  const url =
    "wss://testurl/graphql";
  const query = `subscription ($scope: String = "DEFAULT", $topic: [String]!, $Lines: Boolean = false) {
    update(scope: $scope, subscribeTo: $topic) {
      id
      status}
  `;
  const variables = {
    scope: "DEFAULT",
    Lines: false,
    topic: [
      "test1.*.6ec99981-9ffe-47dd-be33",
      "test1.*.6ec99981-9ffe-47dd-be32.>",
    ],
  };
  const params = {
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "testauth",
      "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol": "graphql-ws",
      Pragma: "no-cache",
    },
  };

  const message = {
    id: 5,
    type: "start",
    payload: { query, variables },
  };

  const response = ws.connect(url, params, function (socket) {
    socket.on("open", function open() {
      console.log("WebSocket connection established.");

      // Send the GraphQL subscription message
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    });

    socket.on("message", function (message) {
      console.log(`Received message: ${message}`);
    });

    socket.on("close", function (code, reason) {
      console.log(`WebSocket connection closed: ${code} - ${reason}`);
    });

    // Handle WebSocket errors
    socket.on("error", function (error) {
      console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
    });

    // Sleep for a specific duration
    socket.setTimeout(function () {
      socket.close();
    }, 10000); // Close the WebSocket connection after 10 seconds
  });

  // Add assertions on the response, if needed

  check(response, {
    "WebSocket connection is successful": (res) =>
      res && res.json().type === "completed" && res.error === undefined,
  });
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the `check()` function has been defined?

Comment: I updated question to show the exact place the error is being displayed @Barmar

Comment: That's clear from the original question. But when did you *define* the `check()` function? It's not a built-in JavaScript function, you have to write it or import it from a library.

Comment: Oh that was what it was. Wonder why lint didn't pick it up. It was the import missing . Thanks @Barmar

Comment: You have to import the function: `import { check } from 'k6';`, cf. https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/checks/. VTC as typo